# Doctrine - working with two id's for persisting

Tags: php, doctrine, entity, flush, persist

I have two entities. Dollar and Wallet. The Dollar already exists in my database and I need to change its wallet. So I had to make api call that should receive dollar_id, and wallet_id and should move dollars to other wallet.

First I gotta find my dollar_id trough my Dollar entity and then to update its wallet_id field with the parameter I passed.

This is my service:

```
public function moveDollar($id)
{

    $dollar = $this->getDollarRepository()->find($id);
    $wallet = $this->getWalletRepository()->find($id);

    if ($dollar instanceof Dollar)
    {
        $dollar->setWallet($wallet);
    }

    $this->em->persist($dollar);
    $this->em->flush();

    return $dollar;

}
```

And my Controller (I think I need to pass both IDs not just one)

Controller:

```
 public function moveDollarAction()
{
    $this->requirePostParams(['wallet_id', 'dollar_id']);

    $this->container->get('app')->moveDollar(
        $this->data['wallet_id'],
        $this->data['dollar_id']
    );

    return $this->success();
}
```

Any guidelines?

Comment: `dollar` and `wallet` entities won't have the same id, so your `moveDollar` method should require 2 ids (as per your controller code where you pass 2 args), then pass those ids into `find` on the appropriate repository.

Comment: $dollar = $this->getDollarRepository()->find($id);    $wallet = $this->getWalletRepository()->find($walletId); Could this be right way? @JonStirling

Comment: Looks promising.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. @JonStirling